# HTML local no muestra imágenes en Webview en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

[image: IMAGEN]

Al correr mi app en Android Studio no se muestran las imágenes de mi archivo local *index.html*. ¿Cómo debo configurarlas?

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega tu còdigo html, recuerda agregar el còdigo como texto y agregar màs informaciòn, revisar [ask] , saludos.

Comment: Hola, actualiza tu pregunta, agregando como texto en lugar de imagen, ya que puede no ser visible para los miembros d ela comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que se tiene que crear una carpeta llamada *assets* como en la imagen, ahí pones tu *index.html* y todo tu sitio web.

[image: Imagen]

Después pones el siguiente código en el archivo *MainActivity.java*

```
package com.example.aqui el nombre de tu aplicacion;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.WindowManager;

import android.webkit.WebSettings;

import android.webkit.WebView;

import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import java.util.Objects;

public class inicio extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio);

        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, 
 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

        webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();

        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }

    @Override
    public  void onBackPressed(){
        if (webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }
    }   }
```

En el archivo *activity_main.xml*:

```
 <WebView

        android:id="@+id/webview"
 
       android:layout_width="412dp"
 
       android:layout_height="730dp"
 
       android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
 
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
 
       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
 
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  
      android:layout_marginStart="-1dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
 
       android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
 
       android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
 
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
 
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
 
       app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
 
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
 
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
 
       app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

lo corres y debe iniciar tu *index.html* y mostrar todo.

Comment: la fotos van en la misma carpeta donde esta tu index.html